# "Requested URL cannot be found" When Website Published on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I develop my website using asp.net c#. There's completely no problem when I debugging my project or test on my local IIS.

but when published on my IIS server, it keep showing "Requested URL cannot be found" error and need about 3 times refresh to show the page normally.

please see the screenshoot here (sorry I'm not allowed to post picture yet):

[image: IIS Error]

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong? Is this error caused by IIS configuration or something?

Comment: Have u Restarted your IIS. After this problem..?

Comment: not yet. I think i'll try your solution. But since i use live server, i think i have to find right time to restart my server. thanks @RJK

Answer (score 1):

This may due to poor IP communication with your IIS Server.

Some tips are here, just try with:

1. Open the IIS Error log file and see what is happening with your hosted website.

2. Try with clearing your browser cache completely.

3. Check with other web sites also, whether they are working or not…

      a) If not, then problem with your internet/intranet connection. 

b)    If yes, then check with your firewall to ensure that is not preventing you to reaching the website/internet.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I have follow your instructions.
1. I open IIS log, and i can't found any error related to this issue.
2,3 I've done this too.